# UICollectionView error with no CollectionView in iOS7

Tags: uikit, uicollectionview, ios7

My app crashes somewhere with the error **"UICollectionView dataSource is not set"**.
This happens only on iOS7 when performing this method:

```
[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
```

My problem is I **DO NOT** have a UICollectionView inside my project!
What could be the problem?

I could not reproduce the problem myself.
I just get reports on these crashes via Crashlytics.